# Red Folder in intelliJ after running springboot:run

Tags: mysql, reactjs, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Hi guys im having an issue with my intellij react project, ive already connected to the MySQL DB from intelliJ..

After running springboot:run, it installs all dependencies for the app after all is done i get a target folder thats red and a package-lock.json thats also red what does this mean?

Im new to react so im trying to run this app locally but when i run the project i get this error:

"Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-22 13:23:20.295 ERROR 6796 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed"

Project has already been built by previous Dev im just trying to get it ti run locally now.

what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Spring-boot is one of the wonderful thing to get started to fast, it
>   does many things automatically. At the same time, missing
>   configuration will lead to this kind of errors.

Please double check application.yaml/.properties and pom.xml for more details.

This error is thrown when **dependencies** are not resolved correctly and **mis-configuration** of dependencies.

If it is a Maven project, right click on project folder and do 'Maven -> Re-Import'. It will fetch the missing maven dependencies.

Also, whatever is mentioned as part of the dependencies should have proper configurations. Let's say for example, you're mentioning mysql as dependency and doesn't provide connection/username/password details then this error occurs.

Please provide more details/error-trace log to provide more accurate answer.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: ive done a reimport as its a maven project, still a red target folder it finishes the build succesfully with exit code 0 but the minute i try running the project it wont run

Comment: looks like you've included some dependencies without providing configuration. Please check if you've everything. Also, check if you're inheriting pom from parent project then make sure you set up correctly.

Comment: can you please share stacktrace with 'debug' enabled? so that we can provide more details to fix the issue.